# Error when running selenium on Apache Airflow- Issue related to ChromeDriver run-Giving Unkown error

Tags: python, selenium, amazon-ec2, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm getting this error when running selenium on airflow. The airflow uses AWS to store the files, I used the following lines of code:

```
OP = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# op = FirefoxOptions()
# op.add_argument("--headless")
OP.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
OP.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
# op.add_argument("start-maximized")
# op.add_argument("--window-size=1100,1000")
# op.add_argument("--headless")
OP.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
OP.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
OP.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
#serv = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver", options=OP)
# s = Service(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
# driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s, firefox_options=op)
# agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
# # print(agent)
path =os.getcwd()
```

The error log is as follows:

```
Broken DAG: [/<my-path>/scraping.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<my-path-name>.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/<my-path-name>/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Since it is showing unknown error I'm not sure where the issue might be, is it with the executable path or something else? I tried using Service() but that gives error as well.

Comment: Should you be running this in headless mode considering that there might not be support right out of the box in the operating system of your ec2 instance for GUI applications?

Comment: Running headless removed the error thank you!

Comment: @fsaa Can you clarify what packages you have in requirements.txt and packages.txt for this to work?

Comment: @phenderbender 

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
WebDriverWait
expected_conditions as EC
NoSuchElementException
ElementNotInteractableException
InvalidSessionIdException
TimeoutException
Keys
GeckoDriverManager
Alert
 Service
Options as OP
ChromeDriverManager
ActionChains
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui
WebDriverWait
expected_conditions
```

Comment: They're all mostly imported from selenium

Comment: @fsaa Rather than the import statements, I was hoping you could provide the actual contents of your requirements.txt and packages.txt (i.e. the specific packages you are installing, and if you are pinning specific versions). Also, if you can paste your entire working DAG in a code block in a comment? If it's working you can mark it as answering your own question/accepted answer